# Fragment in backstack can be Killed?

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack

Fragment in backstack can be killed by something like proccess ?
If the answer is Yes, I have two more questions.

1. what will happen when I return to already-killed Fragment in backstack ?
2. Is it able to intentionally cause such situation ? (For testing my implementation)

Comment: The process can be terminated, yes. In which case the fragment backstack is retained across process death, and the fragments will be recreated on process restart.

Answer (score 2):

fragment backstack is killed when the activity is finished, because every fragment is related to the activity that create it